# R Shiny - Wordcloud2 breaking downloadButton

Tags: r, shiny, wordcloud2

I want to create several wordclouds, using `wordcloud` and `wordcloud2` packages.
I can create a download for the wordcloud created by the `wordcloud` package, but as soon as I render a `wordcloud2`-wordcloud, the download button breaks (only allows to download .html instead of .png).

I've added an example to reproduce it:

```
library("shiny")
library("wordcloud")
library("wordcloud2")
library("tm")

ui <- fluidPage(plotOutput("plot1"), downloadButton('plot1download'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    wordcloud(data(crude))
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderWordcloud2({
    wordcloud2(demoFreq)
  })
  output$plot1download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('wordcloud', '.png', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      device <- function(..., width, height) grDevices::png(...)
      ggsave(file, plot = wordcloud(data(crude)), device = device)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code above works, but if I add another plot (`plotOutput("plot2")`), it breaks:

```
library("shiny")
library("wordcloud")
library("wordcloud2")
library("tm")

ui <- fluidPage(plotOutput("plot1"), downloadButton('plot1download'), wordcloud2Output("plot2"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    wordcloud(data(crude))
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderWordcloud2({
    wordcloud2(demoFreq)
  })
  output$plot1download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('wordcloud', '.png', sep='')
    },
    content = function(file) {
      device <- function(..., width, height) grDevices::png(...)
      ggsave(file, plot = wordcloud(data(crude)), device = device)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Anyone has an idea why this happens and how to resolve the issue?

Comment: in ```ui``` there are two ```plotOutput``` but in ```server```, there are one ```renderPlot``` and one ```renderWordcloud2```. Maybe that causes the problem

Comment: @bretauv I've made a mistake when creating the example, it of course has to be `wordcloud2Output("plot2")`, I've changed it in the question text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the CRAN version of `wordcloud2`. Install the development version from GitHub with 
`remotes::install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2")`
for a fix.

Comment: Possibly related to this: https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2/issues/34